# Passing Variable to Partial - Page Displays symbol instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views, local-variables, partials

Here is the code in my view to call the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "/divbox", :locals => { :smush => "Science" } %>
```

and now here is what's in _divbox.html.erb:

```
<div>
<h1> <%= :smush %> </h1>
</div>
```

I expect HTML output of:

```
<div>
<h1> Science </h1>
</div>
```

But instead I get:

```
<div>
<h1> smush </h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Figured it out:

The reference to "smush" should not have a colon in the partial page:

<%= smush %>

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
<h1> <%= :class %> </h1>
```

To this:

```
<h1> <%= class %> </h1>
```

Note the removal of the colon.  The local variables you pass into your partial are variables in the partial... not symbols.

Also.. don't use "class" at all.  It's a ruby reserved word and even if it does work it's confusing.  Do it like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "/divbox", :locals => { :class_name => "Science" } %>


<div>
<h1> <%= class_name %> </h1>
</div>
```

Or if you really want just "class" use "klass" which is a common substitue...